# Admin Tree in Rails HRM

Tags: ruby-on-rails, admin, activeadmin, ancestry

I've been trying to develop a Human Resource Management system for my organisation and have created the basic infrastructure.  I've now got to the point where I need to create admin authorisation.  My organisation is very much tree-structured and from what I've grasped, what I want to do isn't really facilitated in some of the Admin gems such as Active Admin (although please correct me if I'm wrong!).  I have considered using a `parent_id` field for each level below but am not sure how I would facilitate this in the app.

Effectively, I want the lowest level of employees to be able to view the majority of their personal data minus a few classes such as performance reports/notes and similar attributes, and to be able to edit basic details such as contact details to ensure they are up to date.  Their line manager should then be able to view and all of the details for those employees they are in charge of.  There are about four tiers to the organisation, although I would like to keep it expandable.  There are also multiple line-managers at the second and third tier, which I believe is where the problem in the gems arises.

I have installed the Ancestry gem as I assume this will be the key to unravelling the dilemma but wondered if anyone had any bright ideas.  My current `employee.rb` file is below, just not sure where to go from here.

```
class EmployeesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_employee, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :logged_in_employee, only: [:index, :show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :correct_employee,   only: [:show, :edit, :update]
  before_action :admin_employee,     only: :destroy

  # GET /employees
  # GET /employees.json
  def index
    @employees = Employee.paginate(page: params[:page])
  end

  # GET /employees/1
  # GET /employees/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /employees/new
  def new
    @s3_direct_post = S3_BUCKET.presigned_post(key: "uploads/#{SecureRandom.uuid}/${filename}", success_action_status: 201, acl: :public_read)
    @employee = Employee.new
  end

  # GET /employees/1/edit
  def edit
     @employee = Employee.find(params[:id])
  end

  # POST /employees
  # POST /employees.json
  def create
    @employee = Employee.new(employee_params)
    if @employee.save
      @employee.send_activation_email
      flash[:info] = "Please check your email to activate your account."
      redirect_to root_url
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /employees/1
  # PATCH/PUT /employees/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @employee.update(employee_params)
        flash[:success] = "Profile updated"
        format.html { redirect_to @employee, notice: 'Employee was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @employee }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @employee.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /employees/1
  # DELETE /employees/1.json
  def destroy
    Employee.find(params[:id]).destroy
    flash[:success] = "Employee deleted"
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to employees_url, notice: 'Employee was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_employee
      @employee = Employee.find(params[:id])
    end

        # Confirms a logged-in user.
    def logged_in_employee
      unless logged_in?
        store_location
        flash[:danger] = "Please log in."
        redirect_to login_url
      end
end

    # Confirms the correct user.
def correct_employee
  @employee = Employee.find(params[:id])
  redirect_to(root_url) unless current_employee?(@employee)
end

    # Confirms an admin user.
def admin_employee
  redirect_to(root_url) unless current_employee.admin?
end

# Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
def employee_params
  params.require(:employee).permit(:avatar, :email, :first_name, :last_name, :service_no, :password, :date_of_birth, :gender, :service_start_date, :substantive_rank, :promotion_date, :passport_number, :passport_expiry, :passport_country_of_origin, :nationality, :national_insurance)
end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

In ActiveAdmin the authorization happens when you [access a resource](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/blob/41043fa9aecc47f04eefc6322eea89a7bd4b0876/lib/active_admin/resource_controller/data_access.rb#L88) (or [collection](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/blob/41043fa9aecc47f04eefc6322eea89a7bd4b0876/lib/active_admin/resource_controller/data_access.rb#L30)). It basically uses the action name (eg `index`, `show`, `edit`, `update`, etc) and the model object or class depending on what is available to authorize the request. Without configuration ActiveAdmin does not provide an authorization solution. If you do not configure anything it will just let any user do anything.

ActiveAdmin's authorization method works really well with the cancan gem (or rather its successor the [cancancan gem](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan)) but Pundit is also supported out of the box. Rolling your own adapter is pretty easy as well: you can use any gem with little effort.

For your specific problem:

The relationships between the employees and how you do authorization doesn't necessarily have to affect each other. A role based approach seems to cover your problem pretty well. For example you can create roles for the different hierarchy levels:

- Employee (lowest level)
- Line manager
- Boss of line manager
- Admin (superuser, can do anything)

A user can have multiple roles or roles can be inclusive (line manager can do everything that an employee can). From what I understand the latter is a better fit for your problem.

For a concrete case when someone wants to update a user's contact info (not necessarily her own) you have to check if the user's role permits the update operation and that the current user has access to the other user object. In case of an employee it has to be herself, but a line manager could update her subordinates' contact info as well.

Most authorization libraries provide a declarative way of expressing what different roles can do. I encourage you to take a look at the cancancan gem.

Comment: Thanks, I've been looking at the CanCanCan gem today.  The problem I'm facing now though, it the tree-like structure.  For example say I have three line-managers, I only want them to be able to view/edit their subordinates, hence why I've been trying to incorporate the Ancestry gem.

Comment: Ancestry gem seems to fit in here pretty well. When a line manager wants to edit an employee you have to check whether that employee is the line manager's subordinate or not. Ancestry provides a `descendant_ids` method which would make this check really easy.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try... might take me a few days for trial and error!

Comment: I've tried this, but am having problems as described here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28360925/undefined-method-map-for-nilnilclass-with-ancestry-form